# jQuery - refractoring code (gallery of images)

Tags: jquery, dry

I have created a gallery of black and white pictures (using the CSS's property `filter: grayscale()`).

If a user clicks on one of the pictures I would love that picture to display its actual colours.

I have wrote the following code, however, I don't know how to avoid hard coding and create a dry code (so that if I add 50 pictures I do not have to add extra code).

Please help.

```
$('document').ready(() => {
   $('img').click(() => {
     if ($('img').is("#1")) {
      $('#1').css("filter", "none");
     } else if ($('img').is("#2")) {
       $('#2').css("filter", "none");
     }
etc.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you might just need to use a full `function` and use `this` instead:

```
$('document').ready(() => {
   $('img').click(function() {
    $(this).css('filter', 'none');
  });
});
```

If you have images you don't want this listener to activate on, then give all the images you *do* want the listener to activate on a class, like `galleryImg`, and then do

```
$('.galleryImg')
```

instead of

```
$('img')
```

Comment: Great!!!!! thank you so much!!!
Can you explain to me why it doesn't work if I use an arrow function??

Comment: In an arrow function, `this` is inherited from the outer scope. Only in a `function` is `this` determined by the function's *calling context*. Listeners are called with a calling context of the clicked element.

Comment: thank you! I have never noticed this before. It was extremely helpful!!